# How to change the keyboard shortcut for making links [strg+k] on Wordpress visual editor to another combination?

Tags: wordpress, keyboard-shortcuts, rich-text-editor

Is that possible for wordpress' visual editor? If yes, where and how? Maybe with a certain script? I found NOTHING on google about it!

Thank you, my small fingers will appreciate it ;)

Comment: Yes it should be possible. It will require writing a WordPress plugin that manipulates TinyMCE which is what WordPress uses for the visual editor. Beyond that all I can say is good luck. 
https://codex.wordpress.org/TinyMCE 
https://www.tinymce.com/docs/api/

Comment: ;) As a coding-noob I really cant do it in this life. So I hope that anybody had the same probleme once and created a solution? Maybe a special wordpress plugin? In my simple minds you only have to change the command from strg+k to strg+s or something like that...